# dplyr filter removing NA when that was not specified

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

Consider the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = c("A", "", NA),
             col2 = 5:7)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 "A"       5
#> 2 ""        6
#> 3  NA       7
```

I'm trying to filter out blanks from the data frame above with the following code

```
df %>% filter(col1 != "")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 A         5
```

Why are `NA` removed in addition to blanks? I did not include `df %>% filter(!is.na(col1))`, nor `drop_na()`, nor `na.exclude()`, etc. in my filter call, so I wouldn't think the `NA` row should be filtered out of the data frame.

How do I filter out blanks, but keep the `NA`? An explanation would be preferred as well. Thank you.

Comment: Please study [the `filter` manual](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html): "Unlike base subsetting with `[`, rows where the condition evaluates to `NA` are dropped"

Comment: @Henrik Now it's making sense. `df$col1 != ""` returns `[1]  TRUE FALSE    NA` and that last `NA` is why the `NA` row is dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the default behavior: R simply does not know if `NA == ''` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`

```
NA == ""
[1] NA
```

Therefore the third row is not returned.
If you want to include `NA` as well there are several workarrounds:

```
df %>% filter(coalesce(col1, "x") != "")
df %>% filter(col1 != "" | is.na(col1)
```

Personally, I prefer the first way: `coalesce` substitutes `NA` with a default value (here `"x"`) and then checks if the substituted value is equal to `""`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why that is happening, it shouldn't, but why don't you just assing a value to NA's, remove blanks and then assing those values to NA's again